# Modify the bean created in main application context during Integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

In my springboot application I am performing Integration tests using the following class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AccountLoadApplication.class,
    loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class LoaderTest {
```

AccountLoadApplication.class is a spring boot main class and the actual application has a bean defined like below:

```
  @Bean
  public ResourceLoader recapMvsFileResourceLoader() {
    return new RemoteFileResourceLoader(remoteHostProperties(), new SFTPRemoteFileService());

  }
```

**Also I have a Test Configuration class like below**

```
@Configuration
public class AtddTestConfig {


  @Bean
  public ResourceLoader mvsFileResourceLoader() {
   ResourceLoader recapMvsFileResourceLoader =
        new RemoteFileResourceLoader(remoteHostProperties(), new FakeSFTPRemoteFileService());
    return recapMvsFileResourceLoader;
  }
```

My Idea is that I want to override the bean created in the main application using the new bean defined in the test Configuration file.

But during integration tests the main application bean is considered instead of the bean defined in the test application context?

Is There any other way to achieve what i am trying to achieve  ?

**Additional Info:**

Here are the beans defined in my Application configuration class

```
@Bean
  public RemoteFileService remoteFileService() {
    return new SFTPRemoteFileService();
  }

  @Bean
  public ResourceLoader recapMvsFileResourceLoader() {
    return new RemoteFileResourceLoader(remoteHostProperties(), remoteFileService());

  }
```

Here are the beans defined in my Test configuration class

```
  @Bean
  @Profile("local")
  @Primary
  public RemoteFileService remoteFileService() {
    return new FakeSFTPRemoteFileService();
  }
```

Still the production bean is only created instead of this primary bean.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `@Profile` annotation to enable testing bean only in test context
2. Use `@Primary` annotation on testing bean, so that spring would use test bean instead of production one.

[Here is my Github repository with working example](https://github.com/lkrnac/blog-2015-11-mock-spring-bean-v2) using this mechanism.

Comment: did the same and still not working added some more information under Additional Info in original post

Comment: seems like my problem is with cucumber jvm , normal case is working fine like the example you gave

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you add your test configuration as parameter for `@ContextConfiguration` it resolves problem, e.g.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AccountLoadApplication.class, AtddTestConfig.class},
    loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other changes suggested by @luboskrnac, you have to declare `@ActiveProfiles`; otherwise, your `local` profile is simply ignored.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(AccountLoadApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class LoaderTest { /* ... */ }
```

Note that the above assumes that your `AtddTestConfig` class gets picked up via component scanning by your `AccountLoadApplication` class.